# Umbraco 404 error after install

Tags: .net, http-status-code-404, umbraco, iis-7.5

I have downloaded and setup umbraco on IIS 7.5. I got a 404 page error when I tried running umbraco with Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition.

Here is the error:

Server Error in '/umbraco4' Application.
HTTP Error 404 - Not Found.
Version Information: ASP.NET Development Server 9.0.0.0

umbraco4 is the webroot directory where I have setup umbraco

I don't have experience working with .net

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the Default document in IIS 7.5?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Umbraco can't yet be installed in a virtual directory, which seems to have been what you did. Try to run the web platform installer again and leave the **application name** blank (this is what creates the virtual directory).

Some more information, if you still have problems, can be found in [this thread on the Umbraco forum](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/8157-Windows-Web-App-Gallery---Umbraco-installation-fails) (skip past the first few posts by "sukumarraju").